# Running multiple Rails apps under different sub-URI's for same domain using nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualhost, ruby-on-rails

I was able to successfully configure nginx and passenger phusion. I now have the following configuration

```
server {listen 80  server_name **sub1.example.com** root /home/user/app1/public }    
server {listen 80  server_name **sub2.example.com** root /home/user/app2/public }
```

Now, I want to change it to the following configuration

```
server {listen 80  server_name **dev.example.com/example1** root /home/user/app1/public }
server {listen 80  server_name **dev.example.com/example2** root /home/user/app2/public }
```

I tried using the location directive, but wasn't successful. I'm not even sure if this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The following are my nginx.conf settings

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name dev.example.com;

location = /app1/ {
   root /home/rails/app1/public/; 

   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env development;
}
location /app2/ {
   root /home/rails/app2/public/; 
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env development;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by making use of Passenger Phusion's `passenger_base_uri` directive. Let us assume my domain is `www.example.com`

Now I want to run multiple rails applications for the following URI's

`www.example.com`      - Load Rails App1

`www.example.com/app2` - Load Rails App2

This is how my Server block in nginx.conf would look like:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name  www.example.com;
      root /var/www/app1/public;   
      passenger_enabled on;
      passenger_base_uri /app2;
}
```

Look at how the root is pointing to app1's public folder. And look at the `passenger_base_uri` directive.

Now we need to carry out the final step - symlink app2's public folder to `/var/www/app1/public/app2`, this is done by running the following command:

`ln -s /var/www/app2/public /var/www/app1/public/app2`

Once you create this link, restart nginx and you are ready to serve different Rails apps on the same domain.

References:
[Deploying Passenger Phusion to a sub URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri)

Answer (score 1):

Previous Answer:

```
 server_name dev.example.com/example1
```

is wrong. I am understanding you wanted dev.example.com to go to dev.example.com/example1. For such case, you need to do URL rewrite like below

```
location = / { rewrite ^ http://dev.example.com/example1 ; }
```

Answer after the comment:

From your comment i understood you wanted to serve multiple rails app from within same URI/domain.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /home/user/app1/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_base_uri /app2;
    passenger_base_uri /app3;
    ....truncated...
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_env production;
}
```

Comment: Kaji, what I want to do is instead of creating a sub-domain for every app I have, I would like to do something like this

Have one super sub domain - **dev.example.com**

and then redirect to the app's public folders when requests come. For example, 

    **dev.example.com/app1 - points to app1/public**
    **dev.example.com/app2 - points to app2/public**
    **dev.example.com/app3 - points to app3/public**

I have updated my question with my configuration. It might help you understand the problem better.

Comment: I have updated the answer ...hope that solves for ya'

Comment: Kaji, thanks for the inputs. I stumbled upon the problem again yesterday and this time I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way than the accepted answer here. There is no need to symlink the folders.

#### Deploying an app to a sub-URI or subdirectory

You can also deploy an app to a sub-URI instead of the root URI. For example, suppose that you already have a virtual host for the application /websites/phusion:

```
http {
    ...

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.phusion.nl;
        root /websites/phusion/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

And you want your application, located in /websites/secondapp, to be accessible from the URL http://www.phusion.nl/subpath. To do this, you need to perform the following:

- Create a location with parameter `~ ^/<SUBURI>(/.*|$)`. This is a regular expression that says: "match everything that is exactly , or starts with /".
- Inside the location block, set alias `<PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION PUBLIC SUBDIRECTORY>$1`.
- Inside the location block, set passenger_base_uri `<SUBURI>`.
- Inside the location block, set passenger_app_root `<PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION ROOT>`.
- Inside the location block, set passenger_document_root `<PATH TO YOUR APPLICATIOS PUBLIC SUBDIRECTORY>`.
  Inside the location block, set app_type and startup_file accordingly.
  Here is an example:

  ```
  http {
  ...

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.phusion.nl;
      root /websites/phusion/public;
      passenger_enabled on;

      # This block has been added.
          location ~ ^/subpath(/.*|$) {
              alias /websites/secondapp/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
              passenger_base_uri /subpath;
              passenger_app_root /websites/secondapp;
              passenger_document_root /websites/secondapp/public;
              passenger_enabled on;

          }
      }
  }
  ```

When you are done, restart Nginx. If you installed Nginx via our Debian or RPM packages:

`sudo service nginx restart`

Reference: [article](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri-or-subdirectory)